# Returning two variables in a function in r

Tags: r

I am writing a program that returns two variables in a list such as:

```
returnTwo <- function(){
    results <- c(a = A, b = B)
    return(results)
}

list[a, b] <- returnTwo()
x <- list[a]
y <- list[b]
```

I get:

```
[1] NA
attr(,"class")
[1] "result"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the desired output.

Comment: This looks like an attempt at a Pythonic idiom in R. R does not support that sort of multiple assignment. Additionally, list[a, b] is just sort of syntactically nonsense, given what I think you intend.

Comment: would it work if I just make it:
result <- list(a = A, b = B)?

My end result is I want to separate the two variables in the list after running the function

Answer (score 2):

Really not sure if that's what you're after, but this would work:

```
returnTwo <- function(){
    results <- c(a = 2, b = 4)
    return(results)
}

x <- returnTwo()["a"]
y <- returnTwo()["b"]
```

Or using a list:

```
returnTwo <- function(){
    results <- list(a = 2, b = 4)
    return(results)
}

x <- returnTwo()$a
y <- returnTwo()$b
```